# vitualbox host-only VMs can't communicate

Tags: virtualbox

According to the docs, when I have two VMs in host-only mode, they should be able to talk to each other. I have 2 VMs, both with host only (and a second NAT interface). Both VMs can ping the host, and the host can ping both VMs. each VM has a unique IP and MAC. But for some reason I cant get them to ping each other. I have tried promiscuous mode, which is now disabled, and that did not work. Am i missing something?

Comment: Post for both machines their IP-addresses. They may be on different networks.

Comment: ifconfig on the first is 192.168.56.215, the other is 192.168.56.253. host is 192.168.56.1 on vboxnet0

Comment: Do they have the same subnet mask? Does any of the guests have a firewall working?

Comment: Did you clone them? Verify that the second interfaces have unique MACs too.  If you cloned the first VM, and didn't check "Reinitialize the MAC address of all network cards", you didn't get all new MACs.

Answer (score 0):

[Bob's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/569982/vitualbox-host-only-vms-cant-communicate#comment698330_569982) contained the answer - If they were cloned, verify that the second interfaces have unique MACs too. If you cloned the first VM, and didn't check "Reinitialize the MAC address of all network cards", you didn't get all new MACs."

Comment: This is actually a possible answer. It was worded a little oddly, but I've let bob know, and reworded it into an answer. There's an informal statute of limitations for stealing comments for answers anyway.